# C# reading xml inside certain node

Tags: c#, xml

I need help. I'm trying to figure out a way to read inside a bracket like this one:

```html
<group id = "56"> 
<name>Counter</name> 
</group>
```

In the code, there are mulitiple places where the same pattern comes back, and I would like to get all the group id number's and their name.

This is my code:

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(_XmlFile);
        var results = doc.Descendants("group").Select(x => new
        {
            id = (int)x.Attribute("id"),
            name = x.Attribute("name").Value,
        }).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(results);
```

Thanks

Comment: Name isn't an attribute but a child node

Comment: 1. You cant cast `XElement` to `int`. You need to parse the `Value` which is a `string`. 2. `name` is not an attribute but a child element to `group`.

Comment: Can someone help me correct this?

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen: Actually, `XNode` has cast operators.

Comment: @SLaks: Indeed it does. My Bad... :) Well... It's actually `XAttribute` in this case... Which does not inherit from `XNode`... But `XAttribute` has the same cast operators as well...

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks quite OK, but `name` is an element and not an attribute, so it should be

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(_XmlFile);
var results = doc.Descendants("group").Select(x => new
{
    id = (int)x.Attribute("id"),
    name = (string)x.Element("name"),
}).ToList();

foreach (var x in results)
    Console.WriteLine("id: {0}   name: {1}", x.id, x.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GetElementsByTagName method.

Here is the microsoft article explaining it with examples.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dc0c9ekk(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If i use that, once I put group in the doc.GetElementsByTagName("group"), It returns all the rest of the xml.

Answer (score 0):

"Name" is not an attribute, but a child node. The solution is something like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(_XmlFile);
var results = doc.Descendants("group").Select(x => new
{
    id = int.Parse(x.Attribute("id").Value),
    name = x.Descendants("name").First().Value
}).ToList();
```

Comment: You don't need the `int.Parse` part, but you can cast the `XAttribute` to `int` and `x.Element("name")` is the more accurate way to for getting the first child element of an XElement. Furthermore `x.Descendants` gets the children in all descendent levels. Maybe this is not desired. And if there is no descendant `name` your code will throw an exception

Comment: Thanks, you'r right. I did no see your answer before posting... :)